# Filter for search result with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A quick question:

I'm creating a filter in angularjs to get dynamically a variable and to be used like this from frontend.

```
<div ng-if="(services | searchValue : 'type' : 'facebook').active == true">
...
</div>
```

This is the javascript.

```
.filter('searchValue', function () {
        return function (array, name_var, value) {
            angular.forEach(array, function(v, k) {
                if (v[name_var] == value) {
                    return v;
                }
            });
            return [];
        };
    })
```

Unfortunately even if the result was found it wasn't passed to the template.

If I'll use it like this:

```
{{(services | searchValue : 'type' : 'facebook')}}
```

This will get no value. Any suggestion?

Comment: I think it should be like (services | searchValue : 'type' )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a sample example for the info you've provided. Run the below example check. Hope this helps you.

I guess `ng-if` itself expects only the variable and not the expression. only provide the variable with value i.e `(services | searchValue : 'type' : 'facebook').active` **not the expression**.

```js
var app = angular.module('application', []);

app.filter('customfilter', function() {
  return function(array, name_var, value) {
    var filteredArray = {};
    angular.forEach(array, function(v, k) {
      if (v[name_var] == value) {
        filteredArray = v;
        return false;
      }
    });
    return filteredArray;
  }

});
app.controller('sampleController', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "type": "facebook",
    "active": false
  }, {
    "type": "linkedin",
    "active": false
  }, {
    "type": "twitter",
    "active": false
  }, {
    "type": "google",
    "active": false
  }];

  $scope.anotherdata = [{
    "type": "facebook",
    "active": true
  }, {
    "type": "linkedin",
    "active": false
  }];
});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.17"></script>

<body ng-app="application">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">

    First div - Active : false
    <div ng-if="(data | customfilter:'type':'facebook').active">
      Your div content goes over here
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>Second div - Active : true
    <div ng-if="(anotherdata | customfilter:'type':'facebook').active">
      Second div rendered
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```